# Надо ли подключать какие-то библиотеки к файлу, когда mdk уже установлен?

Tags: minecraft, mod

Я не понимаю, надо ли подключать какие-то библиотеки, а если надо, то какие? Мне нужно обратиться к инвентарю игрока, после поиска нашла метод и то, как получить сущность игрока - player.getInventory(), но меня смутил тот факт, что не было подсказок во время ввода функций, и мне не помешал бы список методов, классов, интерфейсов и тд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключать надо библиотеки net...., и надо было переместить в src/main/java папки